# Converting a html page with jquery into pdf

Tags: c#, jquery, html, pdf, itext

I am trying to find an html parser that can parse an html page even with jquery and convert it to pdf.

previously, i have been using the following code to export an html file to pdf:

```
using System;using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser; 

protected void btnPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=UserDetails.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    this.Page.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0.0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
}
```

But by using iTextSharp dll ,  will i be able to convert an html page that has Jquery UI in it into a pdf?

I ran out of ideas. can any one please give inputs or sugesstions how can we achieve this?

First of all, i would like to know whether this can be achieved at all? is there any dll that has capability to convert an html page(Jquery UI) to pdf?

Comment: The Jquery will not translate to a PDF. But, you can install the Adobe Toolbar and it has a function to convert to PDF from your browser. It will omit the jquery and give you your PDF.

Here is a link: http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/convert-html-to-pdf.html

Comment: Do you really want to rely on a toolbar that have to be installed client side? If the purpose is purely to convert PDF files for your personal use this is probably fine, otherwise a commercial dll is probably the way to go.

Comment: I just need it for my personal use..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Evo PDF](http://www.evopdf.com/) is a commercial software library that can handle this for you.

If you do not mind to use a command line tool, you can have a look at [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)

Comment: Evo PDF is a dll that can be referenced in your .NET project. wkhtmltopdf is a command line tool.

Comment: I just need a dll that can do the job..does it have capability to convert even with jquery UI elements

Comment: Yes it will convert any visual effects as rendered by your jquery code to PDF. This is commercial software so there are some license fees applicable, but you get what you pay for right?

Comment: For eaxmple: i have a show/hide functionality in my page..what can be expected o/p of that page

Comment: If your content is hidden the PDF will not contain the hidden content.  The PDF file will contain exactly what you see on the screen.

Comment: Yes..just now..i have tested it..its rendering the content.but with mis alignments..but i guess this is good enough to have..Thanks for your time,,

Comment: If you are unsure, download the evaluation dll [here](http://www.evopdf.com/download.aspx) and test the library for yourself to ensure that it can do everything you expect before buying it.

Comment: No problem, it is my pleasure. I'm sure you can massage your HTML a bit to fix the alignment issues.

Answer (score 1):

i used **jspdf.debug.js** to solve this ..

```
  function pdfFromHtml(element,gridConfig) { 
                getHtmlForExport(element,gridConfig,"pdf")
                var source='<table>'+$('#exportTable').html()+'</table>'; 
                var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'a0');  
               var margins = {
                    top: 60,
                    bottom: 10,
                    left: 10,
                    width: 720
                };
                pdf.fromHTML(
                    source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
                    margins.left, // x coord
                    margins.top, {// y coord
                        'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF 
                    },
                    function (obj) { 
                        var elementClicked = element;
                        var headerText =  $(elementClicked).text();
                        var fileName;
                        if (elementClicked == undefined || headerText == undefined) {
                            fileName = "pdfExport"
                        } else {
                            fileName = headerText.toString().trim()
                        } 
                            pdf.setFontSize(22);
                            pdf.setFontType("bold");
                            pdf.text(40, 40, fileName+" grid");
                            pdf.save(fileName + '.pdf');
                    }, margins);
    }
```

**getHtmlForExport(element,gridConfig,"pdf")** is the function to get plain html from the table which you want to export to pdf ....

**Note** 
CSS won't be supported as far as i know.